# Como fazer para que apenas uma imagem do looping seja obrigatoria

Tags: php, html, imagem, upload

Bom dia, eu tenho um código que insere imagens com um looping (para o usuário inserir no máximo 5 imagens), agora as 5 imagens estão como obrigatórias mas eu queria deixar só uma obrigatória e o resto opcional.

```
    <div class="crowd-field-wrap">
                                        <label><?php _e('Fotos', 'crowd'); ?> <em><?php _e('(Adicione 5 fotos, uma delas com seu logo ou foto pessoal para aparecer no seu cadastro.)', 'crowd'); ?></em>
                                        </label>
                                        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < CROWD_PLUGIN_MAX_IMAGES; $i++) : ?>
                                            <div class="crowd-file-upload">
                                                <div class="crowd-file-upload-box">
                                                    <input type="file" name="location_image[]" value="" required/>
                                                    <span><?php _e('Clique e envie sua foto', 'crowd'); ?></span>
                                                    <div class="crowd-file-upload-image"></div>
                                                    <a class="crowd-file-upload-trigger"></a>
                                                </div><!-- /.crowd-file-upload-box -->
                                            </div><!-- /.crowd-file-upload -->
                                        <?php endfor; ?>
                                    </div><!-- /.crowd-field-wrap -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, o problema é no atributo `required` que está sendo aplicado em todos os inputs gerados pelo loop.

Neste caso, você pode aplicar o `required` apenas no primeiro input fazendo um `if` quando o valor do `$i` do loop for igual a `0`:

```
<input type="file" name="location_image[]" value="" <?php if($i == 0){ ?> required<?php } ?>/>
                                                                     ↑                  ↑
```

Ou usando `echo`:

```
<input type="file" name="location_image[]" value="" <?php if($i == 0){ echo "required"; } ?>/>
```

Assim, só o primeiro input será obrigatório via `required`.